# Not working DB save on the device

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an application with `SQLiteDatabase`. It's working properly on `AVD`, but not on my phone!

I installed the `apk` and opened it.

What I forgot, what did I wrong ?

Comment: what is not working in your phone , explain the problem .

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall it on your phone and try reinstalling it.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: post your code of the database and the code where you are inserting and retrieving data.
Edit our question and put the code below it.  You got a negative vote because you typically need to as a very specific and almost always include code so people can find your issue.  It can be because of many different reasons and typically something simple.